# Looking for an efficient way to translate values in a huge MariaDB table by information in another, very small table

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, left-join, mariadb

**Problem:**

- In a table `a` with 10 mio rows  I have a column `a.profession_id` of coded professions of customers (0, 1, 2, ...).
- In another very small table `b` I have some (not all) "translations" for these professions (0 = unemployed, 1 = worker, ...).

**Goal:**

- I want to enhance my huge table with the existing Information in an efficient (fast) way.

**Not working:**

- `INNER JOIN` since I don't have all translations
- Classic `LEFT JOIN` since an index on `a.profession_id` will not be used and an index on `b.profession_id` won't Speed things up enogh

  `SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.profession_id = b.profession_id`

**Solution:**

- Non so far, do you have a clever input?

Comment: `enhance my huge table with the existing Information`  dont get it

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely have to do the translation, and can't avoid doing it...

The second best option (purely in terms of database performance and no other considerations) is to ignore the small table and use a static expression in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT r.profession_id
     , CASE r.profession_id
       WHEN  0 THEN 'unemployed'
       WHEN  1 THEN 'worker'
       WHEN  2 THEN '...'
       ELSE ''
       END AS profession_name
   FROM table_with_10_mio_rows r
```

There's drawbacks to that approach, if that profession lookup list isn't static. (If that had been had a static list, and profession isn't an entity in our data model, we might have actually considered implementing profession as a `enum` datatype.)

As a separate step, to help us quickly fill in that CASE expression, we could make use of the lookup table:

```
SELECT CONCAT('       WHEN ',t.id,' THEN ''',REPLACE(t.name,'''',''''''),'''') AS expr
  FROM small_profession_lookup_table t
 ORDER BY id
```

If some professions are much higher frequency, move those to the top of the list.